# Does anybody have a release version (executable) of plugin registration tool for CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I know, for CRM 4.0 we have a C# project and we need to build it for executable, but I am unable to build it at my side.
So If anybody have a built executable then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird that you can't build it. But you can download it here - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqRkf0rNSz72hohp2WnLe1mx4mMmog

Answer (score -1):

You may want to take a look at [XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com) by Tanguy TOUZARD. The latest version allows you to enable the plugin registration tool as a plugin (along with any number of other really useful modules!)